# Hibernate makes extra query to full fill entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to extract entity, that contains **only a specific part of data from DB**. But Hibernate creates extra query, that fully fill my entity.

**EXAMPLE**

Pseudo Query: Select * From ShopUnitDB WHERE prices.date BETWEEN 2022-05-02 AND 2022-05-30;

Pseudo Expected: ShopUnit{1, Name, prices=[{2000, 2022-05-25}, {4000, 2022-05-29}]}

Result: All data from ShopUnitPrice table, related to ShopUnitDB.

**Console log**:

> Hibernate: select shopunitdb0_.id as id1_0_, shopunitdb0_.name as name2_0_, shopunitdb0_.parent_id as parent_i3_0_, shopunitdb0_.type as type4_0_ from shop_unit shopunitdb0_ inner join shop_unit_price prices1_ on shopunitdb0_.id=prices1_.unit_id where shopunitdb0_.id=? and (prices1_.date between ? and ?)

> Hibernate: select prices0_.unit_id as unit_id4_1_0_, prices0_.id as id1_1_0_, prices0_.id as id1_1_1_, prices0_.date as date2_1_1_, prices0_.price as price3_1_1_, prices0_.unit_id as unit_id4_1_1_ from shop_unit_price prices0_ where prices0_.unit_id=?

Look, first query extracts correct entity - that contains only a part based on WHERE ... BETWEEN statement. Next it creates new query to extract all data of sub entity of ShopUnitDB.

I use Spring Data JPA Specification. Also tryed to use `@Query` in JpaRepository. No luck.

Entity 1:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "shop_unit")
public class ShopUnitDB {

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    @Nullable
    private UUID parentId;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ShopUnitType type;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "unit_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<ShopUnitPrice> prices;

    @Transient
    private Set<ShopUnitDB> children;
    ...

    public List<ShopUnit> convertToShopUnitStatistic() {
        return prices.stream()
                .map(price -> new ShopUnit(id, name, price.getDate(), 
                                   parentId, type, price.getPrice()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
...
}
```

Entity 2:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "shop_unit_price")
public class ShopUnitPrice {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "unit_id")
    private UUID unitId;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private LocalDateTime date;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private Integer price;
    ...
}
```

My Service, that call JpaRepository using Spring Data JPA Specification:

```java
@Service
public class ShopUnitService {

    private ShopUnitRepository jpa;

    @Autowired
    public ShopUnitService(ShopUnitRepository jpa) {
        this.jpa = jpa;
    }

    public List<ShopUnit> getShopUnitStatistic(UUID uuid, LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end) 
    {
        unitDB = jpa.findAll(where(idLike(uuid).and(joinPrices(start, end)))).get(0);
        return unitDB.convertToShopUnitStatistic();
    }

    private Specification<ShopUnitDB> idLike(UUID id) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("id"), id);
    }

    private Specification<ShopUnitDB> joinPrices(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            return criteriaBuilder.between(root.join("prices").get("date"), start, end);
        };
    }
}
```

Spring JpaRepository:

```java
@Repository
public interface ShopUnitRepository extends JpaRepository<ShopUnitDB, UUID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ShopUnitDB> {}
```

**UPDATE**

*spring-boot-starter-parent version: 2.6.8*

application.properties

```
server.port=80

spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/goods_warehouse
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Comment: The behaviour is correct so far. There `WHERE` clause only applies to the `ShopUnitDB` entity. Meaning you are getting *all* entities of `ShopUnitDB`with prices within the `WHERE` clause. When you are accessing the prices you are getting *all* containing prices of that specific `ShopUnitDB` because you are not filtering them. TL;DR: You are filtering the result set of the parent entity, not the related child entities of the parent (prices). Therefore you get all prices of that specific parent as the WHERE is only applied to the root / parent entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [@Daniel Wosch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9295125/daniel-wosch)'s comment, i understood the main problem. To solve it, i used to use JPARepository method this `@Query` like this:

```java
@Repository
public interface ShopUnitRepository extends JpaRepository<ShopUnitDB, UUID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ShopUnitDB> {

    @Query("SELECT unit " +
            "FROM ShopUnitDB unit JOIN FETCH unit.prices price " +
            "WHERE unit.id = ?1 AND price.date BETWEEN ?2 AND ?3")
    ShopUnitDB findByIdAndDate(UUID uuid, LocalDateTime dateStart, LocalDateTime dateEnd);
}
```

Note that i used `JOIN FETCH *ShopUnit collection field*` and filtering that data set.

Comment: But i still don't understand, how to make it using Criteria API. I used `root.fetch("prices", JoinType.INNER)` in `ShopUnitService#joinPrices(...)` with no luck.

Comment: Because at this point you are still only fetching the root entity using your `joinPrices` method without fetching the prices. The criteria only applies for the root entity. Then you invoke `prices.stream` on your `ShopUnitDB`. As no prices are fetched before the access to `prices.stream` loads them from database without any filter. In contrast you explicitly load the `prices` in your `@Query` due to the `JOIN FETCH`. Further consider data integrity issues filtering out the Childs. If you e.g. modify the filtered Childs (add or remove one) and persist the parent all filtered out Childs get lost

Comment: you could try: `return (root, query, builder) -> {Join<ShopUnitDB, ShopUnitPrice> join = root.join("prices");  return join.getOn(); };` as specification e.g. "joinSpec" and then `jpa.findAll(where(idLike(uuid).and(joinSpec).and(joinPrices(start, end)))).get(0);` - Sorry. Posting code in comments is not so comfortable

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, this isn't the solution. It returns all data again. After 2 hour, since i've posted my answer, i understand, that Spring Specifications isn't a good idea for my project, because a simple retrieve (without condition) from DB using Criteria creates 2 queries, whereas Spring JPA creates only 1 query.

Comment: You are welcome, just trying to help. TBH I think that there is a way achieving this using Specifications. Maybe it is just a little bit try and discover.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` for `OneToMany` association (which is not recommended) in `ShopUnitDB` entity and criteria APIs to fetch the data. If you use JPQL/Criteria APIs to fetch data with fetchType=EAGER, it will fire 2 queries to retrieve data. Please refer [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/) link for more details.

To fix your issue, I think you should either remove fetchType from `OneToMany` association in `ShopUnitDB` or make it `fetchType = FetchType.LAZY`

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Unfortunately, this isn't the solution. It needs `@Transactional` above my `ShopUnitService.getShopUnitStatistic()`, when i remove (or change to LAZY) `fetch` param.
It makes only one query in service, but when i try to get `ShopUnitDB.prices` field it makes the second query (like the second in the top of the page) - with wrong for me data.

Comment: Can you share implementation of `unitDB.convertToShopUnitStatistic()`?  I tried to reproduce your issue with above classes and it generated only one query for me. I had to tweak `ShopUnitService#getShopUnitStatistic` to comment out unitDB.convertToShopUnitStatistic() as I do not have implementation of that method. So I was wondering if there is something in that method which is the reason behind that extra query. 
Also can you share Spring/Spring Boot and JPA versions you are using?

Comment: Nothing special in method `ShopUnitDB#convertToShopUnitStatistic()` (look at _ShopUntiDB_ entity). `ShopUnit`, used in this method, - is POJO representing an information about single date-price instance. Version was added at the end of the question